# Can the word "communion" be used outside a religious context?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I am looking to find a noun that can be used to describe the social setting/activities going on around a dining table when a family is eating dinner. I find that *"community"* might refer to a larger group of people related more to activities out in the society and not so much within a family setting.

I then found the word *"communion"* to refer to

> 1) A joining together of minds or spirits.
>   (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/communion)

which will fit my case quiet nicely.

However I found that *"Communion"* (spelled with a capital 'C') might only be used in a religious context (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Communion)

What are your thoughts on this? Can I use the word *"communion"* like this:

> The whole family enjoyed the communion they had around the dining table every evening.

Thank you.

Comment: Seems fine to me.  And agrees with your dictionary listing.

Comment: Yeah, the term tends to suggest some sort of spiritual or emotional connection, but it is often used (uncapitalized) in a non-religious sense.

Comment: It might help you if you use  resources other than Wikipedia. There are dozens of online dictionaries published by professionals. Which ones did you check and what did they say?

Comment: The religious (Christian) meaning is not even the first meaning - [Wordweb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=communion), [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=communion+definition&oq=communion+definition&aqs=chrome..69i57.4351j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  It is common non-religious usage, to e.g. say somebody is **in communion with** nature.

Ref http://www.projecthappyhearts.com/uncategorized/5-ways-to-improve-your-well-being-through-communion-with-nature/

This has religious overtones, but is not in any strict religious context.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I believe the word is often suggestive of a religious or quasi-spiritual context (e.g. "She found herself in communion with nature".), because of its inevitable association with ***Holy Communion***, the OED does recognise, and lists as its first meaning a very general one. (It is only when you get to sense 4, that *Holy Communion* is mentioned).

> 1a. The action or fact of sharing or holding something in common with
>   others; mutual participation; the condition of things so held,
>   mutuality, community, union.
>
> ▸a1382   Bible (Wycliffite, E.V.)  (Douce 369(1)) (1850) Ecclus. ix.
>   20   The comunyoun of deth [L. communionem mortis] wite thou; for in
>   the myddil of grenes thou shalt gon in.
>
> c1530   Pol. Rel. & L. Poems (1866) 33   Yf thei be merchauntes,
>   dyvision of heritage is bettyr than commvnion.
>
> 1559   T. Paynell tr. Erasmus Complaint of Peace sig. B.iii,   I
>   behold & se the communion of al things a colledge ioyned together, al
>   one temple, the selfe same lawes, the quotidian & dayly conuentes.
>
> 1591   H. Smith Preparatiue to Mariage 2   Mariage..is nothing els but
>   a communion of life between man and woman, ioyned together according
>   to the ordinance of God.
>
> 1617   F. Moryson Itinerary iii. i. iii. 46   They
>   attribute..hospitalitie to the Brittanes, communion of all things to
>   the Normans.
>
> 1695   R. South Tritheism 192   To affirm mutual Consciousness to be
>   the cause of the Union of the Three Divine Persons in the same Nature,
>   is to confound the Union and Communion of the said Persons together.
>
> 1737   D. Waterland Rev. Doctr. Eucharist 272   By Communion, the
>   Apostle certainly intended a joint-Communion, or participating in
>   common with others.
>
> 1809   S. T. Coleridge Friend 9 Nov. 184   In France there was no
>   public Credit, no communion of Interests.
>
> 1865   G. Grote Plato I. i. 52   Having no communion of nature with
>   other things.
>
> 1921   M. Mortensen Managem. Dairy Plants ii. 11   An association
>   founded upon a contract between two or more competent persons for
>   joining their money, goods, labor, and skill..with the understanding
>   that there shall be a communion of profit among such partners.
>
> 1945   J. West Plainville, U.S.A. ii. 100   Each loafing
>   group..involves a central nucleus of membership, some communion of
>   interest, and frequently an informal meeting place.
>
> 1998   A. J. Nicholls in C. Buffet & B. Heuser Haunted by Hist. xiv.
>   221   If German statesmen and politicians thought of improving
>   relations with the West, they usually looked for some illusory
>   communion of interests with Britain.

**The earliest OED reference to *Holy Communion* with regard to *the Eucharist* is from 1440 (i.e. in the century prior to the Reformation**.